# Bootstrap 4 button color changing on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a the Hugo Bigspring theme with Bootstrap 4 on a website. My primary call to action buttons are orange vs. the secondary green. However, my orange buttons turn green on hover and I cannot figure out why.

Code for the button:

```
<a href="http://localhost:1313/contact" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #F37021!important;
    border-color: #F37021!important;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F37021!important;
    border-color: #F37021!important;
```

You can view the site live here: https://www.bridge12.com.

The orange buttons are on the top right and the bottom of the page.

Really appreciate your help - I've been banging my head against the wall for hours on this one.

Answer (score 1):

This code block in your CSS is changing the color:

```css
.btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary:hover, 
.btn-primary.focus, 
.btn-primary.active {
    background-color: #46812b !important;
    border-color: #46812b !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking your website and inspecting the element this is what is shows
[image]

So it  looks like either bootstrap or another custom CSS is overwriting your code.
Make sure that bootstrap css is always loading before your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Your background-color for btn-primary is set to #46812b!important; which i am sure it is not bootstrap css, that only means that you have that declared somewhere in your css. double check and you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all - this was very helpful. I was loading the style sheets in this order:

```
  <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:1313/css/custom.css">

  <link href="http://localhost:1313/scss/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

Changing it to this fixed it immediately:

```
  <link href="http://localhost:1313/scss/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

  <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:1313/css/custom.css">
```

Huge Thanks!